# Чем отличается LinckedHashSet от HashSet?

Tags: java

Я гуглил, единственное, что я нашел:

> Класс LinkedHashSet расширяет класс HashSet, не добавляя никаких новых
>   методов. Класс поддерживает связный список элементов набора в том
>   порядке, в котором они вставлялись. Это позволяет организовать
>   упорядоченную итерацию вставки в набор.

Но не понял. Кто-нибудь может подробней объяснить?

Comment: Попробуйте ответить себе на простой вопрос. В каком порядке будут элементы в `HashSet`?

Comment: в котором написали

Comment: как добавили, так и будет

Comment: А теперь проверьте свою гипотезу.

Comment: а почему вопрос так сильно заминусован? он нисколько не хуже десятков подобных но с другим знаком рейтинга..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Основное различие в том, что `LinkedHashSet` сохраняет порядок вставки элементов, а `HashSet` - нет. При этом `LinkedHashSet` также как и `HashSet` использует хэш таблицу, в отличие от того же `TreeSet`.

**Пример HashSet:**

```
HashSet dset = new HashSet();
dset.add(new Dog(2));
dset.add(new Dog(1));
dset.add(new Dog(3));
dset.add(new Dog(5));
dset.add(new Dog(4));
Iterator iterator = dset.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
}
```

> Результат: 5 3 2 1 4

**Пример LinkedHashSet:**

```
LinkedHashSet dset = new LinkedHashSet();
dset.add(new Dog(2));
dset.add(new Dog(1));
dset.add(new Dog(3));
dset.add(new Dog(5));
dset.add(new Dog(4));
Iterator iterator = dset.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
}
```

> Результат: 2 1 3 5 4

Comment: а HashSet всегда выдаст `5 3 2 1 4` при таком заполнении? или если добавить второй цикл, то порядок может быть другим?

Comment: @Grundy ответ на этот вопрос не определён. Да и несущественен.

Comment: @Grundy ни одна структура данных не делает порядок обхода случайным намеренно. Разумеется, он будет одинаковый если не менять коллекцию.

Comment: @Grundy нуу в официальной документации сказано, что из-за использования хеш таблиц порядок не будет *гарантированно* постоянным по времени. Так что полагаю ответ да, порядок может быть другим, правда теоретически. В большинстве случаев результат будет тем же.